# HTML, CSS 3 column layout display:inline-block gap

Tags: html, css, layout

I wonder if there is anyone who can help me with the 3 column layout. When I use this code there is always a gap between the wrap div and footer.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">Header</div> 
<div id="wrap"> 
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>    
<div id="clear"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>¨
```

**CSS**

```
*{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;

        }

        #header {
            background-color:aqua;
            height:75px;
        }

        #wrap div{
            display:inline-block;
        }

        #left{
            float:left;
            width:25%;
            height:15px;
            background-color:red;
        }
        #content{
            width:50%;
            height:15px;
            background-color:blue;
        }
        .clear{
            clear:both;
        }

        #right{
            float:right;
            width:25%;
            height:15px;
            background-color:green;
        }
        #footer{
            height:50px;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
```

Here's a fiddle I've been working around with - https://jsfiddle.net/axee/czxwyzqL/3/

I really appreciate all tips!

Comment: Your fiddle has some errors - https://jsfiddle.net/eatjy7cr/ You needed to float the #content div also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten your code I used classes instead of ids and took out some unnecessary parts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .header {
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 75px;
  }
  .left {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .content {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .right {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem glad it was of use

Comment: Might be worth adding that removing the `#wrap div` that was set to `inline-block` was where the whitespace was coming from.  It "output" the `return` character after the wrap div to the screen because it was inline and this creates the whitespace.